# A question about disconnecting finite dimensional Euclidean spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let E be a finite dimensional Euclidean space. If C is a closed subset of E that disconnects E, is it always true that some component of C also disconnects E?

Comment: do you know if $C$ must contain a nontrivial component?

Comment: @Forever Mozart: No, C could be totally disconnected. But if the dimension of E is greater than 1, no singleton could disconnect E and a totally disconnected C could not disconnect E either, since C would Then be zero dimensional.